# Matching a username using Range.Find method in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following code to see if a match happens when a username (Application.Username) exists in an entire column of a certain worksheet when the workbook is open - Under Subroutine: Workbook_Open .

```
Dim rgFound As Range
Set rgFound = Range("C1:C20").Find(Application.Username,After: Range("C1"))
If rgFound Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox("User Access not found in list")
Else
   MsgBox("User Access granted")
End If
```

1.So, there are no match cases - the 1st MsgBox pops up all the time. What is happening here? Any suggestions? N.B. I have two worksheets
2.Also, is there a way of instead setting the rnFound manually to a defined set of cell range, to be set automatically to all the cells in a column ignoring blank ones?

Comment: Try `After:=Range("C1")` ? Also do the cells C1:C20 contain formulae or values? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find

Comment: "exists in an entire column of a certain worksheet" ... which Worksheet? Your Workbook_Open() needs to know which sheet Range("C1:C20") refers to.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. So, I have changed it to the following ```Set rgFound = Sheet2.Range("C1:C20").Find(Application.UserName, After:=Range("C1"))```. But the TRUE condition is not satisfied still.

Comment: You don't really need the After at all (since you don't care where you start). But maybe add `LookIn:=xlValues` to the parameters, in case your cells are formulae. And you can use Range("C:C") to search entire C column (there isn't a noticeable performance hit, on my machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my machine if I have my own user name in column C of Sheet2:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim rgFound As Range
    
    Set rgFound = Sheet2.Range("C:C").Find(Application.UserName, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If rgFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("User Access not found in list")
    Else
        MsgBox ("User Access granted")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your time to answer this- I am still learning this. It worked fine now! the missing argument was LookIn:=xlValues. And there is no need to use a Column function to include a certain column, Range() method does that through that argument, namely "C:C"-very efficient. Finally, is "C:C" passed by value or reference ?

Comment: @Mohammad Good news. I don't know how "C:C" is passed, though I assume by reference as I think that is the VBA default: it doesn't matter as I don't think Range() tries to modify the string. And you taught me something in return: I didn't think you could just use Sheet2, rather than Worksheets("Sheet2") in a Workbook handler.

Comment: @DS_London3 Thanks for your time. Oh yes- Sheet1, Sheet2 are called CodeName. On the other hand Worksheets are Collections and they are either indexed (1,2,3, etc.) or referred to by the Worksheet name in parentheses (String).